# Angular store bearer token from header

Tags: angular, authentication, token, bearer-token

here you see the response of a login post request.
Looks great. the only thing is, this has an empty body and I don't know how to access(and localstore) the Bearer token.

what I can log for now is:
[image]

[image]

this is what I have for now:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpHeaderResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  signIn(name: string, password: string) {
    var postdata = { name: name, password: password };
    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8081/login', postdata, { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('did not work');
        }
      );
  }
```

How do I acces the header part with the bearer token? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this?

```
response.headers.get('Authorization'))
```

Comment: it worked afer putting response.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Authorization");  in the back end: